# SessionID generated by the client in WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf

I was wondering if in WCF it is possible for the SessionID to be somehow set by the client. It is clear that both the client and the service can obtain the SessionID, but what if I want to create the communication channel with a SessionId that is somehow generated with some custom logic in the client? Both the proxy (at the client) and the operation call context (at the service) provide a read-only property for SessionID.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to enable session states. Check this link for more information - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx.

That is offcourse if you have control over the service.